Lognormal probabilistic function
I'm trying to work with a lognormal fuction but I'm not getting the correct results.
I have transform this function obtained in Arena Input Analyzer to this other in AnyLogic. In Arena you get the mean and deviation of the lognormal function and in AnyLogic you have to give the parameters of the normal distribution included, so I apply this calculations.
The distribution is obtained from a sample of real data whose mean is 8.4 and the agents from my experiment in AnyLogic have a mean duration in the delay block of 9.5.





pretty sure its how you interpret the input args. Likely this differs between Arena and AnyLogic. Try it with simpler functions and check the AnyLogic distribution wizard: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/choose-pdf.html
